# returning from spawned thread after a particular action in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am new to thread related concepts.I have program with main function where I call function a() that spawns a thread(NewThread) using boost.now as part of thread i do some initialization of some variable and then start a while(1) loop.

I want give the control to function b() when control reaches inside while(1),

currently it is reaching to b() without starting while loop.

Please guide me.

```
void NewThread()
{
    //initialization of some modules

    //infinite while loop
    while(1)
    {
    }

}
 void a()
{
   this->libThread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&NewThread));
}
 void b()
{
   cout<<"function b";
}
int main()
{
    a();
    b();
}
```

Comment: can you use c++11?

Comment: @mkmostafa:yes we can use c++11,( above code is for just explaining the issue.)

Comment: I've already posted the answer using c++11.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that with c++11. Note that you need to use an atomic variable for the condition, you can't just use a boolean variable. You can also use a condition variable.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>


std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t;
std::atomic<bool> condition(false);

void f() {
    while(true) {
        if(condition) {
            return;
        }
    }
}

void a () {
    t.reset(new std::thread(&f));
}

void b() {
    condition = true;
    t->join();
}

int main() {

    a();
    b();


}
```

update: you need to join the thread after setting the condition. which will block the main thread until the other thread returns.